# Does assigning "prior weights" in a binomial GLM have the same effect as maximizing a weighted likelihood?

Tags: binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model, weighted-regression

I am doing logistic regression where there is some uncertainty about the labels for some of the points. For example, I might only be 90% sure that person 1 is actually a "Yes"--meaning I'm 10% sure that person is a "No". I want to handle this problem by weighting the likelihood.

Specifically, I want to enter two rows of data for each person, one with a "Yes" outcome and one with a "No" outcome. For "Person 1" I referred to above, I would weight the "Yes" row by 0.9 and the "No" row by 0.1. I am doing this in the context of a generalized linear model or generalized additive model. where weights are often used to signify the (in R) number of trials out of which a binomial outcome is taken. In gam (mgcv), the documentation says:

```
weights: prior weights on the contribution of the data to the log 
likelihood. Note that a weight of 2, for example, is equivalent to having 
made exactly the same observation twice. If you want to reweight the 
contributions of each datum without changing the overall magnitude of the 
log likelihood, then you should normalize the weights (e.g. weights <- 
weights/mean(weights)).
```

This seems to fit the bill but I don't know what "prior weights" means here exactly. In a quick simulation, this logic seems to hold up.

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- 1+x+rlogis(1000)>0

x2 <- c(x,x)
y2 <- c(y,1-y)
wts <- rep(1:0,each=1000) # only the first 1000 weights are non-zero
m <- gam(y2 ~ x2, family=binomial, weights=wts)

# produces the same exact fit as m
m2 <- gam(y ~ x, family=binomial)
```

The reason I think `prior weights` might mean the number of trials out of which the binomial was taken, is because when you use fractional weights you get this warning:

```
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

But the results still seem consistent with the weighted likelihood I'm envisioning (e.g. in the example above change weights of 0 and 1 to 0.0001 and 0.9999 and you'll see what I mean)

Comment: In the object returned by gam(), you will find a property called "prior.weights" which should be the same as the weights you pass by "weights" in the gam function call. There is also a "weights" property, which is related to the fitting algorithm and is different than the weights you pass initially. So a partial answer: the numbers you pass to "weights" are indeed what the documentation is referring to as "prior weights".

Comment: Hi @Jonny, Thanks. Do you happen to know if those weights have the effect as likelihood weights? I'm fairly certain the answer is yes but I was hoping to hear from someone who knows.